# How to remove overlay light black background on double-click

Tags: html, css, wordpress

When I double-clicked or single-clicked on the image its overlay light black background.
My question is that how to remove overlay light black background on double-click.
Note: show below attachment image. I double-clicked or single-clicked on the Pepper image.

Please help me.

[image]

Comment: Add a Minimal, Reproducible Example about what you tried

Comment: We can not say anything, if we do not have your code example

Comment: I got answer thanks

Answer (score 3):

Can Please refer or modify your code as given below:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="img_box">
  <div class="image"><img src="Your image path.jpg or png or anything"></div>
  <span></span> <!-- For adding overlay in css -->
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.img_box {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.img_box span {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  display: none;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('body').on('click','.image',function() {
  $(this).next().fadeIn();
});
$('body').on('click','.image + span',function() {
  $(this).fadeOut();
});
```